# select a div preceded by an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i fa  theses two  tags

```
<input type="text" name="aav" class="aav"/>
<div id="aridc" class="aridc"></div>
```

in this  context

```
$(".aav").live("keyup",function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "recapVente.html",
        cache: false,
        data: "exp="+$(this).val()+" article",
        success: function(reponse){
        $(this+"~.aridc").empty();
        $(this+"~.aridc").html(reponse);
        },
        error: function(e){
            $(this+"~.aridc").empty();
            $(this+"~.aridc").html("Votre recherche contien des erreurs");
         }
        });
});
```

to  select  the  div and be sured  that it is the  one following the input i do this

```
$(".aav~.aridc")
```

but  when  i  do this

```
$(this+"~.aridc")
```

i  have  no response

Please how to select the div using

```
this
```

instead of

```
.aav
```

here

```
$(".aav~.aridc")
```

Thanks

Comment: you can show  html and jquery code here?

Comment: maybe try the jQuery prev: http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: Your outside the original function scope!

Answer (score 0):

This is because `this` inside the callback from your ajax method doesn't reference the same object; the context has changed. You can easily solve this by keeping around a reference to the caller:

```
 $(".aav").live("keyup",function(){
      var that = this;

      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "recapVente.html",
         cache: false,
         data: "exp="+$(this).val()+" article",
         success: function(reponse){
            $(that.class+"~.aridc").empty();
            $(that.class+"~.aridc").html(reponse);
         },
         error: function(e){
            $(that.class+"~.aridc").empty();
            $(that.class+"~.aridc").html("Votre recherche contien des erreurs");
        }
    });
```

});

Comment: I don't think this will work .. `that + ""` leads to a syntax error in jQuery internals.

Comment: @tandu you are  right  i ha  an error Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLInputElement]

Answer (score 0):

store this reference to a variable, and use `.next()` to get the sibling:

```
var thediv = this;
...
$(thediv).next(".aridc")
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a DOM Element, not a string, and it cannot be coerced into the selector for the string.  You will simply have to type the string again (or us `.attr` to get some specific attribute selector for the class such as its ID).  Not only that, but you're working with the wrong `this` anyway .. with `.ajax` it will be the `jqXHR` I believe.  You can either use `context:` or store `this` to another variable.

What I find interesting is that `~` works with selector context.  You could use:

```
$input = $(".aac");
$("~ .aridc", $input)
```

and it will work the same as

```
$(".aac ~ .aridc");
```